# Friendly URLS in DotNetNuke for replacing localization settings

Tags: regex, dotnetnuke

I like to change two kinds of URLS in my DotNetNuke setup:

```
/fr-ca/Anything to /fr/Anything
```

AND

```
/en-us/Anything to /en/Anything
```

I went into Host > Settings > Advanced > Friendly URLS and tried this

Match

```
.*fr-ca/(.*)
```

Replace with:

```
.*fr/(.*)
```

But this isn't working...?

EDIT: Based on the answer below I did...

Match

```
(.*/fr)-ca(/.*)
```

Replace:

```
$1$2
```

This made the url look the way I want but now it goes to a broken page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woudl highly recommend [iFinity URLMaster](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Url_Master_DNN_SEO_Urls) to do what you want. I know it is not free but I hesitated a long time and finally got it. I can say it is worth every penny.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Basically whatever is in `()` will get put into groups and these can be recalled by using a number `i` to recall the `i`th group appearing in the regex.

The exact way to recall groups varies from language to language, but I believe `$GroupNumber` should work.

So replace:

```
(.*fr)-ca(/.*)
```

with:

```
$1$2
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that...it's rewriting the url to what I want but now it's going to a broken page?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? Just like a Page Not Found? If the URL is looks right, then the problem is most likely somewhere else. Check that (1) going directly to that URL works, and (2) there isn't any characters that shouldn't be there, like maybe a trailing `/` or leading or trailing white-space. If this didn't help, there may be a problem somewhere else (I don't really know too much about DotNetNuke, so I can unfortunately not help with much beyond the regex).